# Saving a chart as .jpeg file

Tags: image, excel, applescript, jpeg, excel-2008

I have been using Excel charts for some years for creating computer animated movies for teaching physics. However, in converting from VBA to AppleScript I have had trouble saving the charts as .jpeg files. I have tried the script below:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
 set filebasename to get value of cell "MovieName"
 activate object chart object filebasename of sheet 1
 set testfile to "test.jpg"
 save as picture active chart picture type save as JPG file file name testfile
end tell
```

but AppleScript editor tells me the active chart doesn't understand the save as picture instruction. My work-around has been to use the script:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
 set filebasename to get value of cell "MovieName"
 activate object chart object filebasename of sheet 1
 copy picture active chart appearance screen format picture
end tell
```

and then past the clipboard into GraphicConverter to get a .jpeg file.

What am I doing that's stupid?

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set theValue to get value of cell "A1"
    set myNewChartObject to make new chart object at sheet 1 with data theValue with properties {width:100.0, height:100.0}
    save as picture myNewChartObject picture type save as JPG file file name (((path to desktop folder) as text) & "myChart.jpg") as text
end tell
```

Add salt to taste. A small dissection of what's here...

The `make` command is used to create just about every kind of object and returns for you the object that was created. `activate` doesn't, and that's probably why `save as picture` failed, because you didn't have an object to actually save. I would hazard to guess `active chart`  isn't enough for the command to go by because the object that is currently active could change without you realizing it. It is generally a good idea to grab the object, apply it to a variable, and pass that around instead because then you *know* what you have to work with.